# Retrieving an image from the gallery using filepath

Tags: android

Having used the following code to save an image to the file system and save its path in db, i want to retrieve that same photo using the file path WITHOUT launching the gallery for the user to select it. All the suggestions iv found require using intents that launch the gallery.

```
private void createDirectoryAndSaveFile(Bitmap imageToSave, String fileName) {

File direct = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/DirName");

if (!direct.exists()) {
    File wallpaperDirectory = new File("/sdcard/DirName/");
    wallpaperDirectory.mkdirs();
  }

    File file = new File(new File("/sdcard/DirName/"), fileName);
    if (file.exists())
        file.delete();
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        imageToSave.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the path already, try:

```
File imgFile = new  File("/sdcard/Images/sample_image.jpg");

if(imgFile.exists()){

    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());

    ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageviewTest);

    myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

call this type of your function, you can return file path and using this file path, you can show your image on ImageView.

```
  private String createDirectoryAndSaveFile(Bitmap imageToSave, String fileName) {

    File direct = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/DirName");

    if (!direct.exists()) {
        File wallpaperDirectory = new File("/sdcard/DirName/");
        wallpaperDirectory.mkdirs();
    }

    File file = new File(new File("/sdcard/DirName/"), fileName);
    if (file.exists())
        file.delete();
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        imageToSave.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return file.getAbsolutePath();

}
```